# What does aria-controls do that aria-owns does not do?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

People have asked the difference between aria-controls vs aria-owns. The aria-controls is intended parent child relationships based on hierarchy and aria-owns is not.

I want to get very specific.  What exactly does aria-controls do that aria-owns does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Aria Authoring Practices](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/#relations_owning_header) document:

Two relationships expand the logical structure of a WAI-ARIA Web application. These are `aria-owns` and `aria-controls` .  The `aria-owns` relationship completes the parent/child relationship when it cannot be completely determined from the DOM created from the parsing of the markup. The `aria-controls` relationship defines a cause-and-effect relationship so that assistive technologies may navigate to content effected by and changes to the content where the user is operating.

So what that means in practice is that if you have a tab control with a tab panel. The tablist must own the tabs and the tabs control their respective tab panels. The tabs are expected to live hierarchically as children of the tablist and if they do not, then you must use `aria-owns` to point to them.

The tab panels can live wherever you want but you should point to them from the tabs (using `aria-controls`) so the assistive technology can find them and expose them to the user (with keyboard shortcuts for example)

Example of tabs from the [Open Ajax Alliance tab panel example](http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/34/)

```html
<ul class="tablist" role="tablist">
    <li id="tab1" class="tab selected" aria-controls="panel1" aria-selected="true" role="tab" tabindex="0">Crust</li>
    <li id="tab2" class="tab" aria-controls="panel2" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">Veggies</li>
    <li id="tab3" class="tab" aria-controls="panel3" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">Carnivore</li>
    <li id="tab4" class="tab" aria-controls="panel4" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">Delivery</li>
</ul>
<div id="panel1" class="panel" aria-labelledby="tab1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
</div>
<div id="panel2" class="panel" aria-labelledby="tab2" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div id="panel3" class="panel" aria-labelledby="tab3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div id="panel4" class="panel" aria-labelledby="tab4" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

That markup has the required hierarchical relationship between the tablist and the tabs as well as the semantic markup of the fact that each tab controls its respective tabpanel.

The markup could have been done like this (I have omitted the required aria-setsize that would make up for the replacement of the `<ul>` for brevity)

```html
<div class="tablist" role="tablist" aria-owns="tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4"></div>

<div id="tab1" class="tab selected" aria-controls="panel1" aria-selected="true" role="tab" tabindex="0">Crust</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab" aria-controls="panel2" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">Veggies</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab" aria-controls="panel3" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">Carnivore</div>
<div id="tab4" class="tab" aria-controls="panel4" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">Delivery</div>

<div id="panel1" class="panel" aria-labelledby="tab1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
</div>
<div id="panel2" class="panel" aria-labelledby="tab2" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div id="panel3" class="panel" aria-labelledby="tab3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div id="panel4" class="panel" aria-labelledby="tab4" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Comment: Based on the documentation, I do not see any scenario where aria-owns would _not_ work.  But there are cases where aria-controls would not work (tabs).  Am I wrong?  So as a general rule, based on the documentation, when in doubt, we should use aria-owns?

Comment: almost right: aria-owns is required for parent child relationships when the hierarchy does not match. aria-controls should ALWAYS be used, regardless of the hierarchical relationship

Comment: "Always" makes it seem like you are saying aria-controls and aria-owns could be used on the same element.  I don't get that sense from the documentation.  Can you elaborate on what you meant?

Comment: see the examples I added...off the top of my head I cannot think of a widget where the same role might require an aria-owns and an aria-controls but you can see in the example above that the aria-controls is in both examples, whereas the aria-owns is only in the one example where the hierarchy is disjointed

Comment: Oh! Excellent explanation! One last question, is there any scenario where someone would use aria-owns without having a child element aria-controls?

Comment: yes, on something like a button that displays and hides a popup menu. That would not have any children - so no aria-owns but controls the menu - so would have aria-controls